# How to close WatchKit app

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, watchkit

Is there a way to close a `WatchKit` app?

In iOS Simulator there is home button (cmd + shift + h) that will trigger closing app event. I was wondering if there is something similar in `WatchKit` emulator?

**The problem** - I have one `WKInterfaceController` and I never receive "`didDeactivate`" method call.

Comment: I think this is probably due to Apple does not want to show how the Apple Watch might look like until it is released.

Comment: zisoft - doesn't make sense - Apple Watch simulator is already here, it seems they didn't implement/publish "close Watch app" feature.

Comment: @lvp Its still in beta phase. To show home screen they must have default iWatch Apps in a working condition. Which look likes they do not have it or they do not want to show it as suggested by zisoft

Comment: True I agree but on the other hand they can just display black screen when WatchApp is closed - just like when screen is locked in iOS Simulator.

Comment: Agree with @lvp. just black screen would be enough. When you launch external display (38 or 42) mm Watch, it shows black screen at first. They could show it when you close app as well

Comment: Is there an answer to this?

Comment: Currently you can test `didDeactivate ` method by running watchkit app on the simulator and selecting Hardware->Lock, if you want to unlock the watchkit app i.e. want to test `willActivate` just unlock the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 3):

No, this functionality is not currently available in the iOS Simulator.  The current implementation is not a full simulator of the watch, it is just a simulator for WatchKit implemented as an external display attached to the simulated iPhone (not as a separate device).

The closest thing at your disposal is to just turn off the external display by going to the Hardware -> External Displays menu and choosing "Disabled"

Comment: `didDeactivate` not called anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html

```
During testing, you can lock and unlock the simulator to verify that your
activation and deactivation code is working as expected. 
When you use the Hardware > Lock command to lock the simulator, 
WatchKit calls the didDeactivate method of the current interface controller. 
When you subsequently unlock the simulator, 
WatchKit calls the willActivate method of the interface controller.
```